# how can control dynamic retrofit2 response object

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, json-deserialization, jsonschema2pojo

i have 2 endpoints give me Category detail. one is like below just give a list of category children:

```
[{
    "id": 5,
    "title": "cat1",
    "parent": 1
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "cat2",
    "parent": 1
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "cat3",
    "parent": 1
}]
```

and the other give a category object that contain its parent until root item like below:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "title": "cat1",
    "parent": {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "cat2",
        "parent": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "cat3",
            "parent": {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "cat4",
                "parent": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

is it possible handle these endpoints response by one wrapper?
what is best solution in this situation?

Comment: Create two different POJO classes for response ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrofit 2, same name different data type JSON Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44171908/retrofit-2-same-name-different-data-type-json-parsing)